# Use provide gradle dependency in Android Unit Test

Tags: android, junit, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to integrate Dagger 2 to be used in unit tests. Unfortunately whenever I run my test I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider`.

I have the javax dependency added in Gradle like this:

```
depdencencies {
    ...
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

What I tried:
Changing `provided` to `compile`. Adding both `compile` and `testCompile` with this dependency. I also tried `testProvided` but there is no such thing so it didn't work either.

Apparently the problem is that by using provided this dependency is available only compile time. Unfortunately nothing else worked so I am open to any suggestions. If more information is needed, please ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use in AndroidStudio 2.2.3 dagger2 for unit testing with app/build.gradle

```
....

apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'


....
```

Comment: thanks. Although can you provide information why it doesn't work in my case? Also why do I need to use both two `provided` dependencies for javax annotations?

Comment: I think it's just enough provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
Sorry I can not explain it. I studied the Dagger tutorials and used the recommended buil.gradle